# Problems compiling Qt with OCI sql plugin on Linux

Tags: oracle, qt, oracle-call-interface

I am having serious trouble compiling Qt with the OCI plugin.

The Qt version is 5.6.1, and the Oracle instant client version is 12.1.0.2.0. I have installed both the basic and SDK versions, as the Qt online manual asks.

I then try to run the following command:

```
./configure -I /usr/include/oracle/12.1/client64/ -L /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib -prefix /online/daq/antonin/qt_build -plugin-sql-oci -qt-xcb -v
```

Which produces this output:

```
+ cd qtbase
+ /online/daq/antonin/qt_source/5.6/Src/qtbase/configure -top-level -I /usr/include/oracle/12.1/client64/ -L /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib -prefix /online/daq/antonin/qt_build -plugin-sql-oci -qt-xcb -v
Which edition of Qt do you want to use ?

Type 'c' if you want to use the Commercial Edition.
Type 'o' if you want to use the Open Source Edition.

o


This is the Qt Open Source Edition.

You are licensed to use this software under the terms of
the Lesser GNU General Public License (LGPL) versions 2.1.
You are also licensed to use this software under the terms of
the GNU Lesser General Public License (LGPL) versions 3.

Type '3' to view the GNU Lesser General Public License version 3.
Type 'L' to view the Lesser GNU General Public License version 2.1.
Type 'yes' to accept this license offer.
Type 'no' to decline this license offer.

Do you accept the terms of either license? yes

Running configuration tests (phase 1)...
Precompiled-headers support enabled.
g++ -c -fvisibility=hidden fvisibility.c
Symbol visibility control enabled.
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-fuse-ld=gold"
g++ -o libtest.so -shared -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -fPIC bsymbolic_functions.c
Symbolic function binding enabled.
DEFAULT_INCDIRS="/usr/include/c++/4.4.7
/usr/include/c++/4.4.7/x86_64-redhat-linux
/usr/include/c++/4.4.7/backward
/usr/local/include
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/include
/usr/include
"
DEFAULT_LIBDIRS="/lib64
/usr/lib64
/online/daq/lib
/usr/lib
/lib
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7
"
Done running configuration tests.
Creating qmake...
gmake: Nothing to be done for `first'.
Running configuration tests (phase 2)...
Found pkg-config from $PATH: /usr/bin/pkg-config
Determining architecture... ()
g++ -c -pipe -g -std=gnu++0x -Wall -W -fPIC  -I. -isystem /usr/include/oracle/12.1/client64 -I../../mkspecs/linux-g++ -o arch.o arch.cpp
g++  -o arch arch.o   -L/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib 
    Found architecture in binary
CFG_ARCH="x86_64"
CFG_CPUFEATURES=" mmx sse sse2"
System architecture: 'x86_64'
Host architecture: 'x86_64'
C++11 auto-detection... ()
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -std=gnu++0x -Wall -W -fPIC  -I. -isystem /usr/include/oracle/12.1/client64 -I../../../mkspecs/linux-g++ -o c++11.o c++11.cpp
g++ -Wl,-O1 -o c++11 c++11.o   -L/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib 
C++11 enabled.
C++14 auto-detection... ()
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -std=gnu++1y -Wall -W -fPIC  -I. -isystem /usr/include/oracle/12.1/client64 -I../../../mkspecs/linux-g++ -o c++14.o c++14.cpp
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=gnu++1y"
gmake: *** [c++14.o] Error 1
C++14 disabled.
default C++ standard edition auto-detection... ()
g++ -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -fPIC  -I. -isystem /usr/include/oracle/12.1/client64 -I../../../mkspecs/linux-g++ -o c++default.ii -E c++default.cpp
default C++ standard edition enabled.
64-bit std::atomic auto-detection... ()
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -std=gnu++0x -Wall -W -fPIC  -I. -isystem /usr/include/oracle/12.1/client64 -I../../../mkspecs/linux-g++ -o atomic64.o atomic64.cpp
atomic64.cpp:34:18: error: atomic: No such file or directory
atomic64.cpp:37: error: expected unqualified-id before '<' token
atomic64.cpp:37: error: expected ')' before '<' token
atomic64.cpp:37: error: expected initializer before '<' token
gmake: *** [atomic64.o] Error 1
64-bit std::atomic disabled.
64-bit std::atomic in -latomic auto-detection... ()
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -std=gnu++0x -Wall -W -fPIC  -I. -isystem /usr/include/oracle/12.1/client64 -I../../../mkspecs/linux-g++ -o atomic64.o atomic64.cpp
atomic64.cpp:34:18: error: atomic: No such file or directory
atomic64.cpp:37: error: expected unqualified-id before '<' token
atomic64.cpp:37: error: expected ')' before '<' token
atomic64.cpp:37: error: expected initializer before '<' token
gmake: *** [atomic64.o] Error 1
64-bit std::atomic in -latomic disabled.
sse2 auto-detection... ()
g++ -c -pipe -msse2 -g -std=gnu++0x -Wall -W -fPIC  -I. -isystem /usr/include/oracle/12.1/client64 -I../../../mkspecs/linux-g++ -o sse2.o sse2.cpp
g++  -o sse2 sse2.o   -L/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib 
sse2 enabled.
sse3 auto-detection... ()
g++ -c -pipe -msse3 -g -std=gnu++0x -Wall -W -fPIC  -I. -isystem /usr/include/oracle/12.1/client64 -I../../../mkspecs/linux-g++ -o sse3.o sse3.cpp
g++  -o sse3 sse3.o   -L/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib 
sse3 enabled.
ssse3 auto-detection... ()
g++ -c -pipe -mssse3 -g -std=gnu++0x -Wall -W -fPIC  -I. -isystem /usr/include/oracle/12.1/client64 -I../../../mkspecs/linux-g++ -o ssse3.o ssse3.cpp
g++  -o ssse3 ssse3.o   -L/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib 
ssse3 enabled.
sse4_1 auto-detection... ()
g++ -c -pipe -msse4.1 -g -std=gnu++0x -Wall -W -fPIC  -I. -isystem /usr/include/oracle/12.1/client64 -I../../../mkspecs/linux-g++ -o sse4_1.o sse4_1.cpp
g++  -o sse4_1 sse4_1.o   -L/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib 
sse4_1 enabled.
sse4_2 auto-detection... ()
g++ -c -pipe -msse4.2 -g -std=gnu++0x -Wall -W -fPIC  -I. -isystem /usr/include/oracle/12.1/client64 -I../../../mkspecs/linux-g++ -o sse4_2.o sse4_2.cpp
g++  -o sse4_2 sse4_2.o   -L/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib 
sse4_2 enabled.
avx auto-detection... ()
g++ -c -pipe -mavx -g -std=gnu++0x -Wall -W -fPIC  -I. -isystem /usr/include/oracle/12.1/client64 -I../../../mkspecs/linux-g++ -o avx.o avx.cpp
g++  -o avx avx.o   -L/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib 
avx enabled.
avx2 auto-detection... ()
g++ -c -pipe -mavx2 -g -std=gnu++0x -Wall -W -fPIC  -I. -isystem /usr/include/oracle/12.1/client64 -I../../../mkspecs/linux-g++ -o avx2.o avx2.cpp
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-mavx2"
gmake: *** [avx2.o] Error 1
avx2 disabled.
ipc_sysv auto-detection... ()
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -std=gnu++0x -Wall -W -fPIC  -I. -isystem /usr/include/oracle/12.1/client64 -I../../../mkspecs/linux-g++ -o ipc.o ipc.cpp
g++ -Wl,-O1 -o ipc_sysv ipc.o   -L/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib 
ipc_sysv enabled.
zlib auto-detection... ()
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -std=gnu++0x -Wall -W -fPIC  -I. -isystem /usr/include/oracle/12.1/client64 -I../../../mkspecs/linux-g++ -o zlib.o zlib.cpp
g++ -Wl,-O1 -o zlib zlib.o   -L/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib -lz 
zlib enabled.
mtdev auto-detection... ()
Project ERROR: mtdev development package not found
mtdev disabled.
libjpeg auto-detection... ()
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -std=gnu++0x -Wall -W -fPIC  -I. -isystem /usr/include/oracle/12.1/client64 -I../../../mkspecs/linux-g++ -o libjpeg.o libjpeg.cpp
libjpeg.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
libjpeg.cpp:43: warning: 'cinfo' is used uninitialized in this function
g++ -Wl,-O1 -o libjpeg libjpeg.o   -L/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib -ljpeg 
libjpeg enabled.
libpng auto-detection... ()
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -std=gnu++0x -Wall -W -fPIC  -I. -isystem /usr/include/oracle/12.1/client64 -I../../../mkspecs/linux-g++ -o libpng.o libpng.cpp
g++ -Wl,-O1 -o libpng libpng.o   -L/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib -lpng 
libpng enabled.
libdl auto-detection... ()
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -std=gnu++0x -Wall -W -fPIC  -I. -isystem /usr/include/oracle/12.1/client64 -I../../../mkspecs/linux-g++ -o libdl.o libdl.cpp
g++ -Wl,-O1 -o libdl libdl.o   -L/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib -ldl 
libdl enabled.
DB2 auto-detection... ()
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -std=gnu++0x -Wall -W -fPIC  -I. -isystem /usr/include/oracle/12.1/client64 -I../../../mkspecs/linux-g++ -o db2.o db2.cpp
db2.cpp:34:20: error: sqlcli.h: No such file or directory
db2.cpp:35:21: error: sqlcli1.h: No such file or directory
gmake: *** [db2.o] Error 1
DB2 disabled.
InterBase auto-detection... ()
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -std=gnu++0x -Wall -W -fPIC  -I. -isystem /usr/include/oracle/12.1/client64 -I../../../mkspecs/linux-g++ -o ibase.o ibase.cpp
ibase.cpp:34:19: error: ibase.h: No such file or directory
gmake: *** [ibase.o] Error 1
InterBase disabled.
MySQL (thread-safe) auto-detection... ()
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -std=gnu++0x -Wall -W -fPIC  -I. -isystem /usr/include/oracle/12.1/client64 -isystem /usr/include/mysql -I../../../mkspecs/linux-g++ -o mysql.o ../mysql/mysql.cpp
g++ -Wl,-O1 -o mysql_r mysql.o   -L/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib -L/usr/lib64/mysql -lz -lcrypt -lnsl -lm -lpthread -lssl -lcrypto -lmysqlclient_r 
MySQL (thread-safe) enabled.
OCI auto-detection... ()
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -std=gnu++0x -Wall -W -fPIC  -I. -isystem /usr/include/oracle/12.1/client64 -I../../../mkspecs/linux-g++ -o oci.o oci.cpp
g++ -Wl,-O1 -o oci oci.o   -L/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib -lclntsh 
/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libclntsh.so: undefined reference to `lxXmlCvEsc0'
/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libclntsh.so: undefined reference to `lxXmlGEntEscImpl'
/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libclntsh.so: undefined reference to `slnxmul'
/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libclntsh.so: undefined reference to `zt_init'
/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libclntsh.so: undefined reference to `slnxadd'
/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libclntsh.so: undefined reference to `slnxsub'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake: *** [oci] Error 1
OCI disabled.
Oracle (OCI) support cannot be enabled due to functionality tests!
 Turn on verbose messaging (-v) to /online/daq/antonin/qt_source/5.6/Src/qtbase/configure to see the final report.
 If you believe this message is in error you may use the continue
 switch (-continue) to /online/daq/antonin/qt_source/5.6/Src/qtbase/configure to continue.
```

As you can see, there are several undefined references for one of the the OCI .so files. I have tried checking online, but I have found barely any references to these symbols.

Any idea what could be causing this? A missing .so file? Wrong version of the library?

Comment: Oracle client libraries on Linux need LD_LIBRARY_PATH set, or the system search path set with `ldconfig` (see [Instant Client instructions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html#ic_x64_inst)) so that libclntsh.so can find the other libraries.  This isn't true on Windows,

Comment: This is already set. The contents of the file `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-client-12.1.conf` are : `/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/`. I know this one works because if I rename it, the compilation produces additional warnings (libmql1.so and libipc1.so not found)